Performing a function on a matrix to produce a list output
Y: (as a matrix) (2 x 7 , by row)
6  8, 2  5, 2 10, 4 10, 7  8, 4  9, 1  3
y = c(6, 8, 2, 5, 2 ,10, 4, 10, 7, 8, 4, 9, 1, 3)

Y = t(matrix(y, nrow=2))

output (in a list of grouped elements in order):
6 8 7, 5 2 10 4 9, 1 3
I'm trying to achieve the above output using the function linked in the below that takes two vectors a,b and combines on a common element.
I've tried looping but I get lost in managing the lists and was wondering if there is a smarter way to achieve this output. maybe using lapply?
Any ideas or a way forward on this would be much appreciated.
How to combine two vectors by a common element?
I've tried for(i in 1:length(Y[,1])){ ...variations but get nowhere.

Please post your sample data using valid R syntax, e.g., Y <- matrix(c(6, 8, ... The format you have currently makes it difficult to import.

done. Thanks for taking a look.

Are you saying you want a R list? Also can you explain what the process for grouping is?

You should add the requirement about the element's order in your question.

This is a graph theory problem - you can think of each of your values as a node of a graph, and if they occur in the same row then there is an edge connecting the nodes. Your goal is to list the connected components (or clusters).
We can then use the igraph package to do the work:
components = Y |> graph_from_edgelist() |> components() |> groups()
# $`1`
# [1] 1 3
#
# $`2`
# [1]  2  4  5  9 10
#
# $`3`
# [1] 6 7 8


i'll have to learn this package, this is great. TY

is there a way to not sort (order) the components?

@zephryl its partially solved, but i need the components in the order as listed in the output

@B.Jenkins can you describe the order? How do you end up with 6,8,7 as the order for the 1st group and 5,2,10,4,9 as the order for the 2nd group? I am interested in the order not the grouping

I use the function from the other thread, linked. If i have a = c(1,2), b = c(3,1) i join to get 2,1,3

@Onyambu Start 6 -> 8, find next 8 in same column 8 -> 7...

You can also use groups() after components() to get the same output. I.e. Y |> graph_from_edgelist() |> components() |> groups()

@DarrenTsai that does not solve the problem OP is facing. OP needs the results in a particular order

Y |> graph_from_edgelist() |> components() |> groups() doesnt do it. close but.

@B.Jenkins If you can explain a logic for the order based on the input we can probably make it work. I'm confused though, here you say "the function from the other thread", but in the other thread you say "Desired output is 1 3 2 or 2 3 1" so it seems like the order doesn't matter there... And there are 4 answers there so I don't know which one you mean by "the function from the other thread".

@GregorThomas the order is to form a connection between the nodes. for example in group 2, the first appearing is (2,5) but 5 is not connected to any other. 2 Is connected to 2 which in turn is connected to 4 and then 4 is connected to 9. So the order becomes 5,2,10,4,9 as OP has listed. The revious thread is incorrect. Plot the graph and you will clearly see the order

@Onyambu thanks, the plot clears things up a lot. But I worry about a general solution, this simple example doesn't have any branching but it would be easy to add a branch and then there would no longer be a clear order. I wonder if OP's data is reliable to not branch...

@GregorThomas The order is take two vectors A, B join on the common element, dont worry about the second solution because each solution will have a reflection. So for example A = c(1,2,4) B = c(3,5,4) join A and B to gain: (1 2 4 5 3) (or for any length of vectors A and B., keeping the order relative to the joing element. Hopefully that helps,

@GregorThomas seems Problems like this tend to not have branches

I think igraph is a good start, +1! Actually you could use some "path"-related methods to achieve the desired order.

Since answers are being added, I would like to one with the same order as OP requested:
library(igraph)

gr <- graph_from_edgelist(Y, FALSE)
mem <- membership(components(gr))
idx <- which(table(t(Y)) == 1)
v <- tapply(idx, mem[idx], subcomponent, graph = gr)
unname(v[order(match(sapply(v, head, 1) , t(Y)))])

[[1]]
+ 3/10 vertices, from 067185c:
[1] 6 8 7

[[2]]
+ 5/10 vertices, from 067185c:
[1]  5  2 10  4  9

[[3]]
+ 2/10 vertices, from 067185c:
[1] 1 3


@jay.sf In that case, its not about the list being reversed but rather the way the elements appear in the matrix. ie 6 appears before any other node. then we have 5 appearing before node 1

Sticking to the igraph package, you can use shortest_paths or all_simple_paths to retain the vertex order, e.g.,
g <- graph_from_edgelist(Y, FALSE) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("name", value = V(.))

grp <- lapply(
    decompose(g),
    \(x) {
        as.integer(
            do.call(
                shortest_paths,
                c(list(g), as.list(names(V(x))[degree(x) == 1]))
            )$vpath[[1]]
        )
    }
)

which gives
> grp
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1]  5  2 10  4  9

[[3]]
[1] 6 8 7


Here is a solutions based on Gregor's idea. It uses the property that order() is its own inverse function to rearrange the graphs components.
y <- c(6, 8, 2, 5, 2 ,10, 4, 10, 7, 8, 4, 9, 1, 3)
Y <- matrix(y, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

g <- Y |> graph_from_edgelist()
cmp <- g |> components()

# get a permutation of vertices in 'i'
i <- Y |> t() |> c() |> unique() |> order()
# permute the permutation and split
split(V(g)[order(i)], cmp$membership[order(i)])
#> $`1`
#> + 2/10 vertices, from db18a59:
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> $`2`
#> + 5/10 vertices, from db18a59:
#> [1]  2  5 10  4  9
#> 
#> $`3`
#> + 3/10 vertices, from db18a59:
#> [1] 6 8 7

Created on 2024-04-19 with reprex v2.1.0

This is not the correct order. Plot the graph and you will see the needed order. Read through the comments under the other solution. Eg for group 2 the order must either start with 5 or 9

@Onyambu I am not sure that's true, in the linked function all that is needed is the join vertex 10. On each side of it the orders do not seem to matter. Or am I wrong?

you have 4 rows and you join them recursively. ie (2,5), (2,10), (4, 10), (4,9)--you end up with 5->2->10->4->9, exactly like the output OP wrote. Its not joining at 10 alone, you have to join at 2,10 and 4

@Onyambu that is right, the order of each list item matters.  I'm still bamboozled as to how to achieve this.

@B.Jenkins doesn't the solution i posted solve the problem?
